# Refresh CFDIV on AJAX success

Tags: ajax, coldfusion

I have an AJAX call that adds data to my ColdFusion database.

```
 <!---Script to add dashboard link --->     
            <cfoutput>
            <script>
            $(function(){
            //Add a new note to a link
            $("##add_dashboard_links").submit(function(){
               // prevent native form submission here
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        data: $('##add_dashboard_links').serialize(),
                        url: "actionpages/add_dashboard_link.cfm",
                        beforeSend: function(){
                            $('.loader').show();
                        },
                        complete: function(){
                             $('.loader').hide(3000);
                        },
                        success: function() {
                            $("##noteDiv").load( 'templates/dashboard_notes.cfm?techID=#techID#' );
                            $("##addNoteResponse").html('');
                            $("##link_description").val('');
                            $("##link_url").val('');
                            $("##notes").val('');
                            $("##addNoteResponse").append( "Link successfully added." );
                          }    
                    });
                    return false;           
                });
            });
          </script>
          </cfoutput>
```

I also have a CFDIV that binds to some other content

```
      <!---Dashboard Links --->
      <div id="noteDiv" bind="url:templates/dashboard_notes.cfm">
      </div>
```

Here is my modal code located on my template page that contains the form that this AJAX script references (This plugin is found here https://github.com/kylefox/jquery-modal):

```
<!--- Link to open the modal to add a new dasboard link --->
         <div id="DashboardLinks" style="display:none;">
         <h3>Add a new dashboard link:</h3>
         <form id="add_dashboard_links">
            <table width="100%" id="dashboard_table" border="0" cellpadding="5">

              <tr>
                <td colspan="3"></td>
                </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Link Description:</td>
                <td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="link_description" id="link_description" required="yes" message="Please enter the Link Description"/></td>
                </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Link URL:</td>
                <td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="link_url" id="link_url" required="yes" validate="url" message="Please enter the Link URL with http:// -or- https://"/></td>
                </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Link Notes:</td>
                <td colspan="2"><textarea id="notes" name="notes" cols="" rows="">&nbsp;</textarea></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td colspan="3"><input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Add Link" />
            <input type="hidden" name="link_hidden" value="1"><br />
                <div class="loader"><img class="loading-image" src="images/loading.gif" /></div>
                <div class="response" id="addNoteResponse"></div>
            </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            </form>
            </div>
```

Is there a way to refresh this CFDIV tag once I recieve the AJAX SUCCESS?

Thanks.

Comment: cfdiv executes on server side, where as your Ajax request executes at client side. if you want to refresh that cfdiv you have to make another Ajax request and repace the response in respective div

Comment: What would you like the new contents of that div to be?

Comment: I am outputting data from a cfquery. The same data that my script here is adding to. So I am basically trying to refresh the output from my cfquery with my newly added record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `cfdiv` (or any other ColdFusion UI functionality). Since you are already using jQuery, stick with that. Use a plain old HTML `<div>` and keep the same id.

```
<div id="noteDiv" bind="url:templates/dashboard_notes.cfm"></div>
```

Then, in your AJAX call, add this to the `success` block

```
$("#noteDiv").load( 'templates/dashboard_notes.cfm' );
```

You will also need to add that line elsewhere to get the content loaded initially.

Comment: Scott is 100% right. CF's UI tools are much like crutches you can't put a lot of weight on. They support your first steps but you come to regret them later when they won't do what you want or require some rigging and reinforcement. On occasion you find yourself with moretime into duct-taping the crutch than if you'd just learned to walk yourself.

Comment: Awesome. I'll try that and circle back.

Comment: That seems to work great; I've updated my post with the edited code. There is one slight problem though that arises. On my template page, my form is located in a modal. The modal come from a plugin found here [link](https://github.com/kylefox/jquery-modal). The problem is that now after my script completes, it updates the DIV as expected but make the modal automatically disapears yet my browser window still has the opacity overlay. If I then click anywhere, the opacity goes away. But I would still like to have the modal visible so the user can choose to close it. Any ideas?

Comment: That should probably be a separate question. If this answered original question, please mark as such :-)

Comment: Ok will do. I'll post a new question.